# Make an UEFI Bootable

Tags: linux, boot, windows, uefi, mkisofs

lets say I have an custom Windows 10 ISO, that actually is bootable. My problem is, that  its not bootable in UEFI, how exactly can i do that, assuming I want to use mkisofs.
I have created my ISO using

```
mkisofs -allow-limited-size -iso-level 4 -l -R -D -b boot/etfsboot.com -eltorito-platform efi -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 8 -eltorito-alt-boot -no-emul-boot -b efi/microsoft/boot/efisys.bin -o /home/test.iso`
```

And my iso looks like this:

```
Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: ""
    Checksum: 0x55aa
    Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 8 (0x0008)
    Load LBA: 1526 (0x000005f6)
Section Header Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    Section Entries: 1
    ID: ""
Boot Catalog Section Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x07c0
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 2880 (0x0b40)
    Load LBA: 1528 (0x000005f8)

    `
```

Thanks for any help